# AVR adc multichannel isn't reading properly

Tags: adc, avr, atmega

this is a code I made to get reading of 3 ADC channels , I am using the ADC interrupt auto trigger , the first channel works well but after that the readings are weird , I am using potentiometer , so it should read from 0>5000 corresponding to 0>100% , this happens for the first channel ADC0 but after that it reads from 0>2000 corresponding to 0>98% , and the next 2% jumps into 5000 ,

when I tried doing it without interrupts , it worked well , but now I don't know where is the problem

```
volatile u16 digital =0;
volatile u16 temp=1024; //any value>>>>> adc values
u16 analog=0;
static u8 channel = 0;
void Timerfun(void);
void LEDs_var(void);
#define NO_OF_CHANNELS 3


void main(void)
{
    // PIN D2 for EXTI0 Input Pull-up and set A0 as Output Low
    MDIO_voidInit();
    HLCD_voidInit();
    MGI_voidEnable();
    MADC_voidSetToCallback(LEDs_var);
    MADC_voidInterruptEnable();

    MTIMER0_voidSetToCallbackOVF(Timerfun);
    MADC_voidInit();
    MTIMER0_voidInit();

    while (1);
}

void Timerfun(void)
{
    if (channel==NO_OF_CHANNELS)
        {
            channel =0;
        }
    MADC_voidStartConversion(channel++);
}


void LEDs_var(void)
{
    temp=1024;
    digital = MADC_u16GetDigitalValueTrigger();
    if (temp!=digital)
    {
        temp = digital;
        analog = (u16) ((temp * 5000UL) / 1024);
        HLCD_voidClearDisplay();
        //_delay_ms(50);
        HLCD_voidDisplayNumber(analog);
        _delay_ms(2000);
    }


}
```

ADC APIs

```
void MADC_voidInit (void)
{
    CLR_BIT(ADMUX,7);
    SET_BIT(ADMUX,6);

    CLR_BIT(ADMUX,5);

    CLR_BIT(ADCSRA,0);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,1);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,2);

    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,7);
}

void MADC_voidStartConversion(u8 A_u8Channel)
{
    if (A_u8Channel<32)
        {
            // clear the channel 5-bits
            ADMUX &= 0b11100000;
            // Select channel
            ADMUX |= A_u8Channel;
            // start Conversion
            SET_BIT(ADCSRA,6);
        }
}

u16 MADC_u16GetDigitalValueTrigger (void)
{

    return ADCLH;
}


void MADC_voidInterruptEnable(void)
{
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,3);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,5);
// AUTO TRIGGER
    CLR_BIT(SFIOR,4);
    CLR_BIT(SFIOR,5);
    CLR_BIT(SFIOR,6);
    SET_BIT(SFIOR,7);
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You might need to increase the time delay between successive ADC readings.

Comment: @Andyaka didn't work

Comment: First up - use names for the bits as it makes the code easier to read. I think the core problem is that by the time the adc isr code runs, the adc has already begun a new conversion. Then your code chsnges the mux input. Do you really need to use interrupts on your adc? How fast do you need to sample? Consider using one timer to give you a  10ms tick and use cooperative techniques to update leds, trigger adcs etc.

Comment: Try making it about a second if that isn't too tricky. If it doesn't work then at least you've ruled out one hardware problem in some ADCs.

Comment: @Kartman It is my graduation project , so many moving parts so i thought that it will be wise to use interrupts instead of stuffing everything in the main function

I cleared the start conversion bit but nothing changed , now i thought of making the timer counts until 2000ms before starting conversion again so the process don't interfere each other , is this a right logic ?

Comment: Avoid using auto trigger. You seem to read the adc result asynchronously - if you use adc interrupts, then read the adc result in the isr. Maybe you do, but I find your code confusing notwithstanding the poor use of hungarian notation and function naming - ‘getdigitalvaluetrigger’ for getting the adc result.  If your code can tolerate the 100us or so it takes for an adc conversion, then just  start and wait for the conversion.  Interrupts are a double edged sword - used wisely they are a great tool, otherwise they can cut you when you least expect it.

Comment: @Kartman i used normal ADC without interrupt , but it still doesn't work will , i even tried to initialize the adc before every reading and clear the ADEN and ADSC after every reading , and still isn't working , it is weird because what i did should make the avr treat every conversion as a new one , but no , it is still not the true readings ,

Comment: You don’t want to screw around with ADEN or the reference settings unless you need to. The Arduino core code for the adc works. Use that as a reference.

Comment: @Kartman sorry for bothering you , i found that the problem was a Dio definition